# Link to related data in Group Header Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi I have the following list view grouped by a Name so that I can display that name in the group header.

I want to be able to put a link next to the name to access related information and need to pass it the Id for the Name

```
@model IEnumerable<YFA.ViewModels.YoungFFContactListViewModel>

<table class="table">
@foreach (var group in Model
.OrderBy(x => x.YoungFFName)
.GroupBy(x => x.YoungFFName))
{
<tr class="group-header">
    <th colspan="12"><h4>@group.Key - @Html.ActionLink("More Details here", "YoungFFDetailsFC", "YoungFF", new { youngFFId = item.YoungFFId}, null)</h4></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ContactRelationship)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Mobile)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ContactTelephone)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Work)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PrimaryContact)
    </th>
</tr>

foreach (var item in group)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name) @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.YoungFFId)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContactRelationship) @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.YoungFFContactId)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mobile)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContactTelephone)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Work)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PrimaryContact)
    </td>
</tr>
}
}

</table>
```

The data is passed by this controller

```
        public ActionResult FCEmergencyContactList(int branchId)
    {
        var youngFFs = db.YoungFFs.Where(x => x.BranchId == branchId && x.Left == null).Select(x => x.YoungFFId);

        //Populate the list
        var contacts = from s in db.YoungFFContacts
                       where youngFFs.Contains(s.YoungFFId)
                       orderby s.LastName
                       select new
                       {
                           Name = s.FirstName + " " + s.LastName,
                           YoungFFId = s.YoungFFId,
                           ContactRelationship = db.ContactRelationships.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ContactRelationshipId == s.ContactRelationshipId).ContactRelationshipName,
                           Telephone = s.Phone,
                           YoungFFContactId = s.YoungFFContactId,
                           PrimaryContact = s.PrimaryContact,
                           Mobile = s.Mobile,
                           Work = s.Work,
                           YoungFFName = db.YoungFFs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.YoungFFId == s.YoungFFId).FirstName + " " + db.YoungFFs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.YoungFFId == s.YoungFFId).LastName,
                       };

        var viewModel = contacts.Select(t => new YoungFFContactListViewModel
        {
            ContactRelationship = t.ContactRelationship,
            ContactTelephone = t.Telephone,
            Name = t.Name,
            PrimaryContact = t.PrimaryContact,
            YoungFFContactId = t.YoungFFContactId,
            YoungFFId = t.YoungFFId,
            Mobile = t.Mobile,
            Work = t.Work,
            YoungFFName = t.YoungFFName,
        });
        return PartialView("_FCEmergencyContactList", viewModel);
    }
```

How can I access the related Id?

Comment: is it the `YoungFFContactId` or `YoungFFId` which you are trying to add to the link?

Comment: @Alex YoungFFId

Comment: What if you have 2 items with the same `YoungFFName` but different `YoungFFId`? Since you are grouping by `YoungFFName` you cannot get the corresponding id because you don't know which one is it. You can get the list of associated ids from the group items. So basically what you are asking doesn't make sense.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov items in the same group will have the same YoungFFId, I only want one link in the group header not repeat links next to the items

Comment: If all `YoungFFName` are distinct then what's the point of grouping by it? I really have hard time understanding what exactly are you trying to achieve :-)

Comment: They aren't there are several

Comment: Contacts per youngFF

Comment: You can group by 2 properties - .GroupBy(x => new { Name = x.YoungFFName, ID = x.YoungFFId })` and use `@group.Key.Name` and `new { youngFFId = @group.Key.ID}` in the link, but your grouping code belongs in the server, not the view, and you should be using a view model that represents the structure you want in the view

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks, could you point me in the direction of an example of how to do this properly server side please.

Comment: You should have a 'parent' view model containing properties `int YoungFFId`,  `string YoungFFName` and `List<ContactListVM> Contacts` where `ContactListVM` contains properties for `ContactRelationship`, `ContactTelephone` etc (as per your `YoungFFContactListViewModel` but excluding `YoungFFId` and `YoungFFName`, and then use the `.GroupBy()` in the controller and project the results into the view model.

Comment: But there are a few odd things in your queries including accessing `ContactRelationship  = db.ContactRelationships.FirstOrDefault(..)` (ditto for setting the `YoungFFName` property - why are you not using joins, or using `.Include()`?, and why are you projecting to an anonymous object first, then to your view model?